# Why android studio does a gradle sync after applying file templates?

Tags: android, templates, android-studio-3.0

I created my own file template following this article(https://riggaroo.co.za/custom-file-template-group-android-studiointellij/). It's under others/.

It works fine, but every time I use this template, Android studio starts a gradle sync for all my modules.

The file inside the template does not require any external dependancies and consists of only .java files, no xml or other files.

How can I disable such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/templates , this is a default action, there is no way to customize so far

Comment: kindly consider adding relevant details from your link in the answer it is helpful in case the link is moved or removed

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried to figure out how to go without it, but couldn't. So, I had to make a simple program which creates templates for me. How frustrating. I hope intellij or android studio, whatever part does the job, create some tweek in the template feature on the future. It will be such a time saving feature.